# Can't add children.class to set of parent.class

Tags: java, type-erasure

I am trying to add the class object of a children class to a set of parent class object :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Class<? extends A<?>>> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(C.class); //this does not work
    }

    public abstract class A<T> {
    }

    public abstract class B<T, V> extends A<T> {
    }

    // Set<T> could be any other class, it is for demonstration purpose.
    public class C<T> extends B<Set<T>, Set<T>> {
    }
}
```

I get the following error :

```
The method add(Class<? extends Main.A<?>>) in the type Set<Class<? extends Main.A<?>>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<Main.C>)
```

If I remove the '?' from the A, the code compiles, but I don't understand why. Can someone explain me why the "add" is not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**class** is a **'class literal'** which only looks like a static field. 
As per definition, the **type of C.class is Class<C>**, where C is the name of a class.
So you cannot add it to a Set of Class<C<?>> (or in your case Set<Class<? extends A<?>>>)

For further information read **15.8.2 Class Literals** in the Java specs:
 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf